# Depend on multiple gradle tasks in multi project build

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, multi-module, gradle-task

Currently I have task which starts Google Cloud server, runs tests and stops server. It is defined at root project:

```
buildscript {...}
allprojects {...}

task startServer (dependsOn: "backend:appengineStart") {}
task testPaid (dependsOn: "app:connectedPaidDebugAndroidTest") {}
task stopServer (dependsOn: "backend:appengineStop") {}
task GCEtesting {
    dependsOn = ["startServer",
                 "testPaid",
                 "stopServer"]
    group = 'custom'
    description 'Starts GCE server, runs tests and stops server.'
    testPaid.mustRunAfter 'startServer'
    stopServer.mustRunAfter 'testPaid'
}
```

I tried multiple ways to write it something like this, short with only one task. I didn't get how to refer to task from another project and call mustRunAfter on it. This doesn't work (I also tried to refer from Project.tasks.getByPath, root.tasks, etc):

```
task GCEtesting {
    dependsOn = ["backend:appengineStart",
                 "app:connectedPaidDebugAndroidTest",
                 "backend:appengineStop"]
    group = 'custom'
    description 'Starts GCE server, runs tests and stops server.'
    "app:connectedPaidDebugAndroidTest".mustRunAfter "backend:appengineStart"
    "backend:appengineStop".mustRunAfter "app:connectedPaidDebugAndroidTest"
}
```

Is it possible? What is correct syntax to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you're treating `dependsOn` as meaning "invoke this task". It actually means "ensure the result of the depended on task is available *before* the dependent task starts". That's why your first solution didn't work: statements like `testPaid.mustRunAfter` only affect the actions of the `testPaid` task itself, not its dependencies.

Anyway, you can get the behaviour you want using `dependsOn` and `finalizedBy`, but they have to be declared in the build file of the **app** subproject.

**app/build.gradle:**

```gradle
task connectedPaidDebugAndroidTest {
    //
    //...
    //

    dependsOn 'backend:appengineStart' // Ensure appengineStart is run at some point before this task
    finalizedBy 'backend:appendginStop' // Ensure appengineStop is run at some point after this task
}
```

Then, you can run your tests simply with `gradle app:connectedPaidDebugAndroidTest`. If you really want to define a task in the root project to run the tests, then that's easy too:

**build.gradle:**

```gradle
task GCEtesting {
    dependsOn = "app:connectedPaidDebugAndroidTest"
}
```

Comment: First code block actually works. Second one is what I would like to accomplish. I want new task to depend on those 3 and then manage order of dependent tasks. Is it possible?

Comment: No - that breaks the implicit contract of tasks: that their behaviour and ordering shouldn't be affected by other tasks. Each task should be a wholly-defined definition of how to obtain a particular _result_, just like with pretty much all build systems.

If you want some behaviour that can be reused by various tasks in various different ways, then use plain old java/groovy methods, not tasks. You can define a method on a subroject that's invokable from another project by adding a closure to its extension container: `ext.someMethod = { /*code*/ }`

Comment: So there is no way of leaving test task without changes while creating new task? Maybe I want to make tests without server start and stop other time?

Comment: Then your are testing 2 different _scenarios_ (one with servers, one without), so you should have 2 different sets of test result, and hence 2 different tasks. As I said, if both these scenarios require you to take the same (or very similar) set of actions, then define a method, just like you would in java, and invoke it from the action definitions of both tasks.

Comment: Can you give example, link?